# Need to know if each field has changed, how should I model this in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

So I have a class with three fields that maps to a table using hibernate

```
Class Widget
{
     String field1;
     String field2;
     String field3;
}
```

On application startup a number of instances these widgets will be added to the database from an external files, but when I exit the application I need to know which (if any) of these fields have been changed by the user since the application was started, so the changes can be saved back to the files. I also need to store the original value for logging purposes.

I can't work whether I need a status field in the table or whether there is already a way of doing this using Hibernate/Database.

EDIT:A good solution to the program was given below . however the main reason I am using Hibernate is to reduce memory consumption so storing the original values when changed is not a good solution for me , I want everthing stored in the database. So I have create this new question [How do I store a copy of each entity I add to database in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431299/how-do-i-store-a-copy-of-each-entity-i-add-to-database-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an entity like the following you can track changes on one of it's field (while preserving its original value too).

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test", name = "test")
public final class Test {

  private static final int ORIGINAL = 0;
  private static final int CURRENT = 1;

  private Integer id;

  // holds the original and current state of the field
  private final AtomicReferenceArray<String> field = new AtomicReferenceArray<>(2);

  @Id
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Transient
  public String getOriginalField() {
    return field.get(ORIGINAL);
  }

  @Basic
  public String getField() {
    return field.get(CURRENT);
  }

  public void setField(String field) {
    this.field.compareAndSet(ORIGINAL, null, field);
    this.field.set(CURRENT, field);
  }

  @PreUpdate
  public void preUpdate() {
    System.out.format("Original: %s, New: %s\n", getOriginalField(), getField());
  }

  ...
```

}

If there is a single row in a database like this:

```
     id: 1
  field: a
version: 2011-12-02 11:24:00
```

before the *field* gets updated (say, from `a` to `b`) you'll get the following output.

```
Original: d, New: b
```

The original value gets preserved even if the the entity is updated multiple times and both state can be accessed through the corresponding getters (*getField* and *getOriginalField*—you can get more creative than me in the naming :).

This way, you can spare yourself from creating version columns in your database and also can hide the implementation details from clients.

Instead of an `AtomicReferenceArray` you could use arrays, lists, etc, to track all changes like this way.

The `@PreUpdate` isn't necessary of course, but this way you can be notified of changes in the entity's state and atomically save the updated fields into file. There more annotations like these: see the documentation for [*javax.persistence*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html) for other annotation types.

Comment: I just read up about versioning and it appears it is intended for optmistic concurrency control, not something Im trying to do so is the right tool for the job. Also I wanted to knwo which fields had changed, not just if the enty had changed.

Comment: okay I think in my case it would make most sense to just add a status field for each field

Comment: "I wanted to knwo which fields had changed" You didn't indicated this in your question. However I gave an answer to this latter problem of yours also after I've read your other comments. Anyway, if you want to know that your entity's `field1` have changed or not in a particular time-span, then you have to have a *snapshot* of the  entity's state in that interval's extremes (its start and end *points*).

Comment: I wrrote "I need to know whether the value of any of these field have been changed by the user since the application was started", but you are correct this can easily be misinterpeted, sorry.

Comment: I have a feasible solution for you: just came up with it, I'll scratch _this_ and write a new one.

Comment: Actually, sorry Ive relaised that I need the original value of each field as well not just whether they have changed, so actually all I need to do is make a copy of each widget. So that if I start the app and load one widget, I need two instances of that wideget in the database, one of them that I just look at and never modify. Unsure if hibernate helps with that or whether I handle the copying myself

Comment: If you have tables properly normalized then you can't duplicate a row in a database. You can have two rows with the same values, but those will have to have different primary keys (composite or not). If you create another table for the duplicate values, then you have to create separate entity classes for it also ... that seems too complicated. Also, you've said that you need the original value of the field. I'll update my proposal to give a solution for that. However, I advise you to properly phrase your question next time (you can edit it), because this is getting out of hand.

Comment: Yes, sorry Im just getting to grips with Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql then you can get table's last update time from information_schema database like

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM  `information_schema`.`tables` 
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tableName'
```

Or else simple solution will be to add a column for update time stamp. By this you can even monitor which particular row has been updated.

Comment: so I need an status for each field then, I dont just want to know if something has chnaged I want to know what has changed

Comment: @user294896 If you want to know for specific rows then AFAIK you must need a updateTimeStamp(status) column in db.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to synchronize with files as soon as you save into database, You can use the Hibernate event mechanism to intercept any save to database and save it to file, here's a [sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/EventYourOwnSaveOrUpdateEventListener.htm) doing that.

Comment: thanks but that is not what I want do. I  want to say at some point which are all Widgets that have been modified, and whihc fields of those widgets have changed